# Parse ISO timestamp using Java 8 java.time api (standard edition only)

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, string-parsing, java-time

I'm having trouble getting milliseconds from the epoch out of the string in the example. I have tried this three different ways so far, and the example shows the latest attempt. It always seems to come down to that the [TemporalAccessor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAccessor.html) does not support [ChronoField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html). If I could successfully construct an instance of Instant, I could use [toEpochMilli()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toEpochMilli--).

```
String dateStr = "2014-08-16T05:03:45-05:00"
TemporalAccessor creationAccessor = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.parse(dateStr);
Instant creationDate = Instant.from(creationAccessor);
```

Please give concise answers (don't construct a formatter from scratch) and use only the java 8 standard distribution (I can do it with Joda, but want to avoid dependencies).

**Edit:** Instant.from in the code above throws: `java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain Instant from TemporalAccessor: {OffsetSeconds=-18000},ISO resolved to 2014-08-16T05:03:45 of type java.time.format.Parsed`

Comment: The code you have posted compiles and runs fine. What version of Java 8 are you using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to be a bug which I found in all tested versions before and including `jdk1.8.0_20b19` but not in the final `jdk1.8.0_20`. So [downloading an up-to-date jdk version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) would solve the problem. It’s also solved in the most recent jdk1.9.

Note that the good old Java 7 way works in all versions:

```
long epochMillis = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")
                  .parse(dateStr).getTime();
```

It also supports getting an `Instant`:

```
Instant i=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX").parse(dateStr).toInstant();
long epochMillis = i.toEpochMilli();
```

But, as said, a simple update makes your Java 8 code working.

Answer (score 11):

## Your Code Works, As Of Java 8 Update 51

Your code is working now, as of Java 8 Update 51 on Mac OS X Mountain Lion. The [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25741762/642706) by [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) that there may have been a bug in earlier versions of Java. Understandable as the java.time framework is brand-new in Java 8.

Here is a modified copy of your code.

```
String dateStr = "2014-08-16T05:03:45-05:00";
TemporalAccessor creationAccessor = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.parse( dateStr );
Instant instant = Instant.from( creationAccessor );
long millisSinceEpoch = instant.toEpochMilli( );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant, ZoneOffset.of( "-05:00" ) );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "dateStr: " + dateStr );
System.out.println( "instant: " + instant );
System.out.println( " millis: " + millisSinceEpoch );
System.out.println( "    zdt: " + zdt );
```

When run.

```
dateStr: 2014-08-16T05:03:45-05:00
instant: 2014-08-16T10:03:45Z
 millis: 1408183425000
    zdt: 2014-08-16T05:03:45-05:00
```

## Canonical Method:
`parse(CharSequence text, TemporalQuery<T> query)`

You may want to accomplish your parsing using an alternate method.

The class doc for `DateTimeFormatter` mentions that the usual way to parse should be a call to [`DateTimeFormatter::parse(CharSequence text, TemporalQuery<T> query)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.temporal.TemporalQuery-) rather than [`DateTimeFormatter::parse(CharSequence text)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-).

So instead of this:

```
String input = "2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]" ;
TemporalAccessor temporalAccessor = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.parse( input ) ;
```

…do this, where we add a second argument, the argument being a [method reference in Java 8 syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), to call the conversion `from` method (in this example, `ZonedDateTime :: from`):

```
String input = "2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]" ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.parse( input , ZonedDateTime :: from ) ;
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println("input: " + input );
System.out.println("  zdt: " + zdt );
```

When run.

```
input: 2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]
  zdt: 2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since instant can't properly be represented using a long (they've designed the API to not have Y 2040 issues, when a long is no longer sufficient), you have to use a combination of two methods

getEpochSecond()

and

getNano()

The former gets you the # of seconds from epoch, and the latter gives you the # of nanoseconds that have passed since that same second.

Comment: Those are both methods on Instant, which I cannot get an instance of. If I could, then Instant#toEpochMilli() would be the answer.

Comment: A long millisecond value will last far beyond 2040. You are confusing it with an int second value which expires in 2038.

Answer (score 0):

Instant.from(creationAccessor).toEpochMili() should sort you, at least according to the [ThreeTen javadoc for TemporalInstant](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/temporal/TemporalAccessor.html). [ThreeTen](http://www.threeten.org) is the reference implementation of javax.time. Let me know if this works for you or not by leaving a comment.

Comment: depends on how accurate you want to be.  toEpochMillis will work, but as documented, at some point in the future (2040 ish), this will throw an exception.  Let's hope java is still around then.

Comment: By 2040-ish, it will hopefully be replaced with javax.datetimetwentythirtyeight anyway.

Comment: The more I look at the given time and [wikipedia's sample](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), the more I suspect this is a JDK bug... *sigh*